# Common iterator for vector and map C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I've got a "general" container, which has an underlying map or vector. For example:

```
class Container
{
  typedef variant<vector<string>, map<string, string>> Data;

public:
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();

private:
  Data mData;
};
```

I wish to give an user a common iterator. it would be easy to dereference such an iterator, as it could always return a pair of values.

```
struct pair
{
  string key;
  string value;
}
```

Where in case of an array, key value would be an index.

But I'm not sure how to handle iterator correctly. Currently I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class iterator
{
  public:
    iterator(vector<string>::iterator it);
    iterator(map<string, string>::iterator it);
    ..

  private:
    bool m_isMap;
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    map<string, string>::iterator it;
};
```

But this implementation is a little bit messy. Is there any better approach? Or even a ready to go boost solution?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: A user should be able to iterate over a container and get all it's values or generate a string with values mapping - {key : value}.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I'm asking, what problem are you trying to solve with _the whole thing_? What does `Container` achieve?

Comment: Ok. It's just a part of code. Container is kind of "variant" class. It could also store a string for example. Then it should be able to iterate over characters. It (is|will be) mainly used for input and output a data.

Comment: I think @LightnessRacesinOrbit point is to ask why you are even binding these two containers together to form this other container. What is the problem your new container solves that regular containers do not?

Comment: @Dejwi: You're still not understanding. _Why_ do you feel you need this "kind of 'variant' class"?

Comment: It is a part of requirements. My part of code has to provide such an object. Similar to "Value" used in jsoncpp. Unfortunately I cannot base on jsoncpp and jsoncpp itself has an approach similar to this one.

Comment: @Dejwi I think I agree with LRIO; your question seems to be like "how do I enumerate the doors on my house-car". The first question should be "... what are you trying to accomplish with it" as it's a weird combination.

Comment: Do you really want to return e.g. `{ "0", "first" }` from `container.front()` when it contains a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. The usual thing to do, however, is to make the function that takes the iterator(s) a template function and just instantiate it for the various iterators required.
1. You can use boost's `any_iterator`:

   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html
2. You can use Boost Property Map which is precisely to create a consistent interface to get/put properties using a key.

   - use `make_iterator_property_map` for the vector (the index is the key)
   - use `make_assoc_property_map` for the map (using the map's key)

Of course this still requires the code to take the propertymap as a generic argument (because the types vary). However, you can pave over that using a `dynamic_property_map`:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/property_map/doc/dynamic_property_map.html

0. Roll your own type erasure. You could use Boost Type Erasure as a building block (it rocks). But of course, you can do it without boost too. This might be a benefit